# How can I write a log::Record into a csv::Writer in a single pass?

Tags: csv, rust

The `log` function defined in the `Log` trait accepts a `Record` parameter.
As far as I can tell, in order to obtain the payload as a string, I need to do something like:

```
let mut s = String::new();
write!(s, "{}", record.args());
```

The next step is to use `csv::Writer`:

```
let mut writer = csv::Writer::from_path("/path/to/csv");
writer.write_field(s);
// optionally write more fields
```

What would be the simplest way to do that in a single pass?

Answer (score 0):

[`record.args()`](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.14/log/struct.Record.html#method.args) returns [`&std::fmt::Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html), it implemented `Display` trait, and [`csv::Writer::write_field`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.write_field) accepts a `field` that implemented `AsRef<[u8]>`. So this is working:

```
let mut writer = csv::Writer::from_path("/path/to/csv")?;
writer.write_field(record.args().to_string())?;
```

Comment: Isn’t that also making two passes on the payload? One in to_string and one in write_field?

Comment: @Shmoopy This is unavoidable because [`csv::Writer`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Writer.html) does not implement `Write` trait. And due to Rust's [orphan rules](https://rust-lang.github.io/chalk/book/clauses/coherence.html#the-orphan-rules), you cannot implement the `Write` trait for it in your own crate. You should ask the `csv` developers about this, it's possible they just forgot.